# Me da error este codigo por que?

Tags: php, html, css

Quiero poner una condicion para que cambie la clase del html en funcion del valor de una variable pero no me funciona.

```
<?php if ($score[1]>$score[2]): ?>
<h4 id="medio" class="victoria">VS</h4>

<?php if ($score[2]>$score[1]): ?>
<h4 id="medio" class="derrota">VS</h4>
<?php else: ?>
<h4 id="medio" class="empate">VS</h4>
<?php endif ?>
```

Me podeis ayudar gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido Angel. Por lo que veo tu primer if no lo cierras. ¿Te has dejado de incluir algo de código?

Comment: Muchas gracias solucionado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Al ser tres evaluaciones, debes implementar una estructura usando `elseif`, teniendo en cuenta lo que dice [el Manual de PHP al respecto](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php).

Para simplificar el código y no tener tanta mezcla, puedes guardar el resultado de las evaluaciones en una variable y usarla al final:

```
<?php 
    if ($score[1]>$score[2]):
        $class="victoria";
    elseif ($score[2]>$score[1]):
        $class="derrota";
    else:
        $class="empate";
    endif;
    echo "<h4 id=\"medio\" class=\"$class\">VS</h4>";
?>
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfecto, gracias soy nuevo en php lo mio es JS

Comment: @Angel Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.